# Setting a NiFi property to null

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a situation where I want to create and set a property to a value of another property as long as the other property exists.

I have tried to achieve this using the UpdateAttribute process configured as follows:

```
Property                  Value
   A           ${"B":isNull():ifElse(null, ${"B"})}
```

But syntax checker gives a red curly brace at the end of the line  (I've tried null, Null, NULL).
And if I run it anyway, I get a processor exception - unable to evaluate expression due to Unexpected token 'null'.

I'm beginning to think this is not just about finding the correct token to represent null.  Is it because properties cannot be set to null?  If so, what's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: try this - `${B:isNull():ifElse('NULL', ${B})}` but NULL is string here

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde  Thanks for your answer. But as you say, it does put 'NULL' character string in A.  I think I may have to do this in 2 stages. 1st stage copy B to A. 2nd stage will check if A is empty and delete A if empty.

Comment: Or set up a Rule where A will be created only if B exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted using Rules.
Condition : ${"B":notNull()}
Action : Attribute A, Value ${"B"}

Since I have several attributes I want to condition using this Rule and I want all the results in the same output FlowFile, I select FlowFilePolicy to 'use original'

See https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html

Answer (score 0):

I achived that by setting UpdateAttribute Processor "Delete Attribute Expression" property:
${B:isEmpty():ifElse('B','')}